# JSON support dependency not working

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, restful-url

I am Implementing Java Restful web services In maven project.
I am able to Produce XML responce successfully but if I add JSON Support dependency My `Apache Tomcat` not Starting it gives an error when I run my project
**Error Message:**
[image]

**pom.xml** file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**My Controller Class:**

```
package com.test.restfull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.test.trex.model.TrexReport;
import com.test.trex.service.TrexService;



@Path("/getSO")
public class GetDetails {

    TrexService obj= new TrexService();

    @GET
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<TrexReport> getSoStatus() {

        List<TrexReport> messages = new ArrayList<>();

        TrexReport m = new TrexReport();
        m.setCreated(new Date());
        m.setAuthor("User1");
        m.setId(1);
        m.setMessage("My First Message");
        messages.add(m);
        return messages;
}
```

**Exception Message:**

```
Oct 12, 2017 4:22:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

check {TOMCAT_HOME}/logs/catalina.out for more possible errors in this scenario. Clean the project, remove the server and try running it again on tomcat 8.

Comment: Hi Khirul, I tried with Clean the project, remove the server Still same issue. :(

Comment: Try running it on GlassFish